# Bypass startup code to prevent image from crashing on startup

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I have a new Pharo 1.3 image, that I've just loaded with SS, DBX, and my apps. I'm using the latest Cog VM on OSX10.6. The VM crashed randomly, and when I tried to restart the image, it exits immediately. The stack trace shows my app getting an error reading an open socket, that of course, no longer exists.

What I would like to know, is there a way to pass a script or command line option, and have Pharo bypass my app and startup? I think I know exactly where in my code that I need to change, so even if I could filein (from the command line) a patch, that would work too.

Basically, what I need is a safe mode to boot the image, and manipulate code, save and restart normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try passing a .st file to the image. However, the offending code may be executed before the file is processed (all the startup methods are executed before processing the argument). In this case, your only option is to build a debug VM. After you manually edit the VM or use gdb to avoid executing your socket code, fix the code in the now-running image and save. Then you'll be able to run it on a regular VM. For building a VM, see Mariano Martinez Peck's excellent posts/screencasts [like this one](http://marianopeck.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/how-to-debug-the-vm/). Also, see [this thread on the Pharo](http://forum.world.st/Oops-I-put-a-halt-in-a-startup-method-td3800163.html) list about my experience doing this.

n.b. this may take quite a while, so consider the tradeoff with simply starting a new image.

Comment: Thanks Sean. Working my way through the VM posts from Mariano. Great thread from you to get started at this. I just rebuilt my image, but having a generic solution, like custom VMs would be very useful. The images don't fail often, but when they do, its a real pain to try to recover them, or find out what happened.

Comment: Yes, your suggestion for a safe-mode is also a great idea - keep pushing (and even feel free to invent one)! Our Pharo community is a great crew of volunteers, mentors, and partners. Also there are some great, simple persistence strategies which make data much more robust in the face of image crashes (see Ramon Leon's blog post; the code for which I packaged on Squeaksource). Also, Metacello can help by making your projects-with-dependencies load in one or two lines of code.